# Import a vm image to a new host machine with virt-manager

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, restore

I need to recover a guest machine with Windows 2003 on a new host server on Centos 7 with virt-manager. I've shut down a guest machine and simply copied its .img file from /var/lib/libvirt/images.

Then I've tried to restore it using virt-manager, I've pointer virt-manager to my .img file, checked to install NAT network (default) and it worked - system's been restored. But it has no Internet connection, LAN works and my guest pings from other guests and can ping host-machine and other guests, but there is no Internet. Maybe I've done a wrong restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, it's better to export/import the complete VM information, not only the disks. If you still have access to your original host, find your VM's definition (XML format). In Ubuntu it resides under */etc/libvirt/qemu*, not sure about CentOS and likes. You can just copy it to the same location (with *libvirt* service stopped) or import using `virsh`. You may have to edit XML before importing to change network name, storage path, etc, because you've created them before.

A chance is that your current problem is related to MAC address change or a routing issue.